# PCI bus interface in Python

Tags: python, pci

We have a board which can be connected on the PCI bus of the motherboard. We can read the base address and whatever related information through the customized software of the board. Reading and writing through the board is done without any problems which means that there shouldn't be any problems at the operating system level. We need to access the data through the Python interface. Are there any libraries or piece of code which I can send the data to that address? The board is already supported for C++ and VB libraries. What i need in fact is an interface of PCI bus in python.

Comment: Why not just expose the C++ library interface to Python?

Comment: I am not familier with this whole procedure, can you expalin more? Do you mean that i should use ctype module in python and read the related libraries? Do you know any decent code in c which works properly with PCI interface?

Comment: What OS is this for? On Linux, you _can_ read & write data to given addresses using /dev/mem, so I guess you could use that to talk to your PCI device, although I've never done that sort of thing myself.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is having [pciutils](https://github.com/pciutils/pciutils) library then you can use [libpci](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libpci) python librarie API's for accessing PCI through python, Where "python libpci" uses ctype libraries to access 'pciutils libpci' shared library. The 'pciutils libpci' uses os dependent interfaces to access PCI memory region, For example in Linux it uses either procfs or sysfs to read or write memory.